# Unconscious prejudices of "pure" versus "applied" mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, mathematicians

Once upon a time (true story) a highly respected “pure” mathematician saw the following expression:
$$
M = A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top
$$
and instantly said it's the identity matrix. But if $A$ has many more rows than columns, then $M$ is actually a symmetric idempotent matrix of low rank, the mapping $x\mapsto Mx$ being the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A.$

I have this suspicion: that “purity” of this sort is correlated with assuming matrices are square. And that this is only one instance of tacit simplifying assumptions correlated with “purity.”

(Paul Halmos, who was quite “pure,” wrote *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*, in which the spectral decomposition of of Hermitian matrices is treated as important and (if I'm not mistaken) the singular-value decomposition, very important in applications, does not appear. So maybe that's another instance.)

Are there

- informed views about the merits or demerits of my suspicion; or
- other data points of interest?

Comment: Could you expound upon the difference between “prejudice” as you use it and *bias* as it might be used?

Comment: Indeed, "bias" might be the more appropriate way to frame the question.  And what about bias, vice-versa?

Comment: While I more-or-less agree that purity-based simplification is a thing, I don't find the "example" given here to be compelling at all. First of all, it sounds more like a silly slip-up more than anything significant *(especially given the "instantly" bit - I've "instantly" said some pretty stupid things, e.g. that a problem could be solved using an infinite set of odd multiples of $6$)*. More importantly, since maps between vector spaces of different dimensions are interesting to applied **and** pure mathematicians I don't see how this can be construed as a purity-based simplifying assumption.

Comment: Meanwhile, your point about Halmos doesn't seem to be about simplification at all, but rather judgment of importance/interest/value (which I think is much more common). I think at present this question is too broad and unfocused, to be honest, and a case could also be made for opinion-based.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : Of course all mathematicians are concerned not infrequently with linear transformations between spaces of different dimensions. But I had in mind initial assumptions in certain contexts.

Comment: About the Halmos bit: the Singular Value Decomposition is a straightforward consequence of the Spectral Theorem together with the Polar Decomposition, and this is a more natural view for an operator theorist, since these two make sense in infinite dimension, even in the non-compact case.